# mySQL for server in React Native

Tags: database, reactjs, realm

Just wondering if realm is used as a database for local, do we need the other one such as MySQL for server database in app development?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specifics of the application you are building. If all you need to do is to store data locally to be available between app launches then Realm is all you will need. If you want to persist data on a server or to share data between multiple clients then you will probably need a backend of some sort.